# Does reducers added via combineReducers use Immer for state updates?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I am a complete newbie in using Redux/Redux Toolkit and am working on writing a small application.
My current store and reducer setup looks something like below:

```
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer
})
  
...
...
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    settings: SettingsReducer,
    user: UserReducer,
})
```

I have written `SettingsReducer` and `UserReducer` something like below:

```
const SettingsReducer = (state: SettingsState = initialSettingsState, action: SettingsReducerActionType) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        ...
        ...
        default: return state
    }
}

const UserReducer = (state: UserState = initialUserState, action: UserReducerActionType) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        ...
        ...
        default: return state
    }
}
```

I would like to know if my `UserReducer` and `SettingsReducer` will use `Immer` for updating state? Looking at the Redux documentation it mentions using functions `createSlice` and `createReducer` will allow Immer usage so I wanted to get some confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Redux's documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers)

> Redux Toolkit's createReducer and createSlice automatically use Immer internally to let you write simpler immutable update logic using "mutating" syntax. This helps simplify most reducer implementations.

By not using `createReducer` and `createSlice`, you're not using Immer.

Comment: This is correct.  combineReducers just combines the reducers.  It will not change the reducers themselves.  The reducers will not use Immer unless they are created with an RTK helper.

Comment: Does `Immer` solve the problem of deep copying objects too? This is off topic but I could use your expertise. :)

Comment: JavaScript has a built in function for deep copying objects, it's called structuredClone - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone. It can be polyfilled if required https://github.com/ungap/structured-clone